# Salvar arquivo em colunas

Tags: matlab

Eu preciso salvar os dados de um arquivo `.txt` para abrir no excel. Eu consigo salvar os dados, de maneira que cada loop seja salvo um abaixo do outro, mas não consigo salvar em colunas.

As duas primeiras colunas são iguais, o que é diferente são as duas ultimas colunas.

function:

```
for i =   1:9
     vi = vi+(i+10-i);
     misv = (C1.*(1-exp(-C2.*si))-C3.*si).*exp(-C4.*vi);
     misvc = (C1.*(1-exp(-C2.*si))-C3.*si).*mi0.*exp(-C4.*vi);

     TempA = [si; Fsi; misv; misvc];

     FilenameA = strcat(Filename,' - Slip Function','.txt');
     fid = fopen(FilenameA{1},'at+');
     fprintf(fid, 'Slip Slip_Function Slip Slip_Function_Dry Slip_Function_Cont \n');
     fprintf(fid,'------------------\n');
     fprintf(fid,'%.3f %.3f %.3f %.3f\n',TempA);
     fprintf(fid,'------------------\n');
     fclose(fid);
```

Arquivo `.txt`:

```
Slip Slip_Function Slip Slip_Function_Dry Slip_Function_Cont 
------------------
0,000 0,000 0,000 0,000;
0,010 0,224 0,208 0,187;
0,020 0,399 0,370 0,333;
0,030 0,536 0,497 0,448;
0,040 0,643 0,597 0,537;
0,050 0,727 0,674 0,607;

Slip Slip_Function Slip Slip_Function_Dry Slip_Function_Cont 
------------------
0,000 0,000 0,000 0,000;
0,010 0,224 0,193 0,173;
0,020 0,399 0,344 0,309;
0,030 0,536 0,461 0,415;
0,040 0,643 0,554 0,498;
0,050 0,727 0,626 0,563;
```

Answer (score 0):

Se compreendi o que você quer, você quer ter apenas as duas colunas iniciais e depois ter apenas os dados que você gerou em colunas. 
Para fazer, isso, uma maneira é criar os dados em apenas uma matriz e salvar esta matriz.

Exemplo:

```
iii=9;
%initialize variables
tempALL=zeros(10,iii*2+2);
tempALL(:,1)=(1:10)'; %primeira coluna
tempALL(:,2)=(2:2:20)'; %segunda coluna

%escreva elas na formato que você que ter a saida.
for a=1:iii;
    tempALL(:,a*2+1)=tempALL(:,1)*a; % aqui são os dados da terceira coluna
    tempALL(:,a*2+2)=tempALL(:,2)*a; % quarta coluna.
    %perceba o aumento no indice da matrix que está sendo salvo os dados
end
%veja que salvo fora do loop, acessos a arquivos em loop em geral não é uma boa pratica.
dlmwrite('myFile.txt',tempALL,'delimiter','\t','precision',3)
```

veja [as opcões](https://se.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/dlmwrite.html) do `dlmwrite`.

Olhando o meu aquivo de saída, os nome não aparecem. Uma solucão é você pode criar o arquivo da maneira que você está criando, porém com os nomes ordenados em apenas uma linha. Salve apenas os nomes e feche o arquivo. Use o `dlmwrite` com a opcão `-append` e você terá os nomes e os dados. Posso colocar um código pra isso outro momento.

Caso não seja isto, deixe um comentário que posso tentar melhorar.

Comment: Olá Guto,

Obrigado pela ajuda, eu rodei a rotina que você enviou e ela está salvando eum uma unica linha. as duas primeiras linhas são dois paramentros que são usados para calcular os demais, como eu não consigui salvar todos os parametros no mesmo arquivo cada vez que o loop roda ele salva as duas colunas novamente mas elas so precisam ser salvas no primeiro loop.

Comment: @JulianoCardoso, Não entendi ao certo seu comentário. Funcionou ou não?
O seu problema inicial eram colunas, e o arquivo da minha maneira salva a quantidade que eu entendi que você queria de colunas: 2 iniciais mais os resultados.

Comment: Deculpe Guto, realmente funcionou, eu que havia errado ao colocar os parametros da minha função na sua rotina..

Muito Obrigado.....

Comment: Guto deixa eu te fazer outra pergunta, quando eu uso o dlmwrite o resultado do arquivo fica desta maneira  1 2 1 2 2 4 3, ou seja todos os resultados são escritos em uma linha, usando o fprintf(fid,'%.5f %.5f %.5f\n',Temp_AS_DT); ele escreve três colunas mas ele vai preenchendo os dados linha a linha, ou seja ele usa todos os dados da coluna 1 da matriz Temp_AS_DT para preencher a 1 linhas das 3 colunas depois vai para a segunda linha até completar as três colunas até terminar os dados da primeira coluna da Matriz Temp_AS_DT ai começa com os dados da segunda coluna.

Comment: @JulianoCardoso Como vc é um usuário novato, vale a pena a recomendacão. 
Um comentário - em geral - não é o lugar pra perguntas novas. Um comentário tal qual os primeiros são relevantes, pois podem mudar/esclarecer a pergunta/resposta. Este último não pois requer mais explicacões não necessariamente relevantes a sua pergunta inicial. Uma opcão é modificar a pergunta, mas neste caso você usaria a resposta como pergunta, que muda completamente o foco pergunta/resposta. Recomendo uma nova pergunta com um exemplo, e coloque um link pra esta pergunta pra ter o contexto.

Comment: @JulianoCardoso Caso você coloque outra pergunta, coloque o link aqui pois daí posso dar uma olhada tb (mas sem promessas de responder).